# How can I use animated PNG in UWP?

Tags: c#, vb.net, xaml, uwp

I have this animated [**png from this api**](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/items/1263950/ebe6b674deca163b28423e3b925bd36b0f0f357b.png) and I want to put it on someone profile photo, but it's only showing as 1 frame photo.

I so that there is [BitmapDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder?view=winrt-19041) but i don't know how to set it up in XAML.

[image]

**Can anyone help me please?**

I have tried so far this and gives me a frozen img:

```
<Image   Source="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/items/1263950/ebe6b674deca163b28423e3b925bd36b0f0f357b.png" />
```

and this gives me a bad B&W img :

```
<BitmapIcon   UriSource="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/items/1263950/ebe6b674deca163b28423e3b925bd36b0f0f357b.png" />
```

Comment: There is no API to support animated PNG image in UWP. We suggest you use a GIF image as the [animated iamge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage?view=winrt-19041#animated-images). You can get more information about animated GIF image referring to the [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlAnimatedGif).

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT the problem is that the API responses is only A png , so when i convert the img to gif  anywhere  i get an bad blur img.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to share your thoughts. As of this time, however, 
there is no API supportting to animate a animated png image provided by your web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i posted this i just noticed that this is an old post but maybe someone will have some use of it in the future.

Actually, there is something that you can work with:

Sorry, I Just noticed that this is a UWP question, not sure how WPF translates to UWP, but my answer works in WPF, but you can use the box class and just need to modify the converter.

I have modified this library https://github.com/murrple-1/APNGManagement and it works.

It was written in C# and it targets winforms .NET framework 4.xx something. But I used it in VB.NET and on .NET5.0 with no problems.

What I did is to clone the repository and add a reference `APNGLib` to my project (the .dll file that you get from compiling/building).

Then created a usercontrol (WPF) to hold the image:

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="ApngImg"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ToolSet"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="APNGcontrolIMG" Width="200" Height="200"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

in the code behind the xaml:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports APNGLib

Public Class ApngImg

    
    Sub New()
        DataContext = Me
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim pngFilePath As String = "C:\ebe6b674deca163b28423e3b925bd36b0f0f357b.png"
        Dim png As New APNG 'picturebox
        Using s As Stream = File.OpenRead(pngFilePath)
            png.Load(s)
        End Using
        Dim boxy As New APNGBox(png, APNGcontrolIMG)

    End Sub
```

Then eddited the original `APNGViewer_WinForms`.`APNGBox` (translated from C# to VB.NET)

All i did was add `container` as `System.Windows.Controls.Image` to constructor, added private property for the container and added a function, which converts `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` so that the image could be shown in wpf image control.

```
    Public Function Convert(ByVal src As Bitmap) As BitmapImage
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        src.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        Dim image As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()
        image.BeginInit()
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        image.StreamSource = ms
        image.EndInit()
        IMGcontainer.Source = image
        Return image
    End Function
```

Notice that the return is not needed in my case because i could not figure out how to update property when conversion was made so that the image control would notice. Instead I just set the container Source property.

This is pretty hacky, but works.

Here is the full APNGBox class:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports APNGLib
'addition made by dumi
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Windows.Media.Imaging
Imports System.ComponentModel
'---------------------------------------------------------
Public Class APNGBox
    Inherits PictureBox
    'addition made by dumi
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub
    '---------------------------------------------------------
    Public Property CurrentFrameNumber As Integer
    Public Property Images As IList(Of Bitmap)
    Private APNGFile As APNG
    'addition made by dumi
    Private IMGcontainer As System.Windows.Controls.Image
    '---------------------------------------------------------
    Private timer As Timer
    Private playthroughs As UInteger
    Private _ImageBitmap As BitmapImage

    'addition made by dumi
    Public Property ImageBitmap As BitmapImage
        Get
            Return _ImageBitmap
        End Get
        Set
            _ImageBitmap = Value
            NotifyPropertyChanged(NameOf(ImageBitmap))
        End Set
    End Property
    '---------------------------------------------------------

    Public Sub New(ByVal png As APNG, Container As System.Windows.Controls.Image)
        APNGFile = png
        'addition made by dumi
        IMGcontainer = Container
        '---------------------------------------------------------
        CurrentFrameNumber = 0
        Images = New List(Of Bitmap)()
        InitImages()
        'addition made by dumi
        ImageBitmap = Convert(Images(0))
        '---------------------------------------------------------
        Image = Images(0)
        Size = Image.Size
        playthroughs = 0

        If APNGFile.IsAnimated Then
            timer = New Timer()
            timer.Interval = APNGFile.GetFrame(0).Milliseconds
            AddHandler timer.Tick, New EventHandler(AddressOf timer_Tick)
        End If
    End Sub

    'addition made by dumi
    Public Function Convert(ByVal src As Bitmap) As BitmapImage
        Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        src.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        Dim image As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()
        image.BeginInit()
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        image.StreamSource = ms
        image.EndInit()
        IMGcontainer.Source = image
        Return image
    End Function
    '---------------------------------------------------------
    Private Sub timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If APNGFile.MaxPlays = 0 OrElse playthroughs < APNGFile.MaxPlays Then
            NextImage()
            Dim f As Frame = APNGFile.GetFrame(CurrentFrameNumber)
            timer.Interval = f.Milliseconds
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitImages()
        If APNGFile.IsAnimated Then
            Dim current As Bitmap = New Bitmap(CInt(APNGFile.Width), CInt(APNGFile.Height))
            Dim previous As Bitmap = Nothing
            ImageRender.RenderNextFrame(current, Point.Empty, APNGFile.ToBitmap(0), Frame.BlendOperation.SOURCE)
            Images.Add(New Bitmap(current))

            For i As Integer = 1 To APNGFile.FrameCount - 1
                Dim oldFrame As APNGLib.Frame = APNGFile.GetFrame(i - 1)
                Dim prev As Bitmap = If(previous Is Nothing, Nothing, New Bitmap(previous))

                If oldFrame.DisposeOp <> APNGLib.Frame.DisposeOperation.PREVIOUS Then
                    previous = New Bitmap(current)
                End If

                ImageRender.DisposeBuffer(current, New Rectangle(CInt(oldFrame.XOffset), CInt(oldFrame.YOffset), CInt(oldFrame.Width), CInt(oldFrame.Height)), oldFrame.DisposeOp, prev)
                Dim currFrame As APNGLib.Frame = APNGFile.GetFrame(i)
                ImageRender.RenderNextFrame(current, New Point(CInt(currFrame.XOffset), CInt(currFrame.YOffset)), APNGFile.ToBitmap(i), currFrame.BlendOp)
                Images.Add(New Bitmap(current))
            Next
        Else
            Images.Add(APNGFile.ToBitmap())
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub NextImage()
        CurrentFrameNumber += 1

        If CurrentFrameNumber >= APNGFile.FrameCount Then
            playthroughs += 1
            CurrentFrameNumber = 0
        End If
        'addition made by dumi
        ImageBitmap = Convert(Images(CurrentFrameNumber))
        '---------------------------------------------------------
        Image = Images(CurrentFrameNumber)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ToImage(ByVal index As Integer)
        'addition made by dumi
        ImageBitmap = Convert(Images(index))
        '---------------------------------------------------------
        Image = Images(index)
        CurrentFrameNumber = index
    End Sub

    Public Sub Start()
        If timer IsNot Nothing Then
            timer.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub [Stop]()
        If timer IsNot Nothing Then
            timer.[Stop]()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is image added to the original github code using winforms:
[image: THis is image added to the original github code]

And this is my result in wpf:
[image: THis is from my wpf app]

Comment: Thanks so much!! Super easy explanation , I'm speechless. All what i could find was viewing it throw a webView.  to update after conversion `Private Sub OnCurrentImageChanged()     Return CurrentImageChanged?.Invoke()   End Sub
        Public Event CurrentImageChanged As Action` And in the page subscribe to update the bindings  `Public Sub New()        InitializeComponent()       APNGBoxitems.CurrentImageChanged += AddressOf update1    End Sub

    Private Sub update1()   Return Bindings.Update()  End Sub `  Thanks again! i will try to modify it to UWP

Comment: np, took you almost a year to notice my reply. I dont like WPF and with binding because when you have alot of elements with a lot of binding the application user interface starts to lagg. Im looking for a better framework to work with.